# PHP RegExp for url string

Tags: php, regex

**Example strings:**

```
accuracy-is-5

accuracy-is-5-or-15

accuracy-is-5-or-15-or-20

package-is-dip-8-or-dip-4-or-dip-16
```

**My current regexp:**

```
/^([a-z0-9\-]+)\-is\-([a-z0-9\.\-]*[a-z0-9])(?:\-or\-([a-z0-9\.\-]*[a-z0-9]))*$/U
```

No fixed length, part:

```
\-or\-[a-z0-9\.\-]
```

can be repeated.

Bot now from string "accuracy-is-5-or-15-or-20" i get:

```
Array ( [0] => accuracy-is-5-or-15-or-20 [1] => accuracy [2] => 5 [3] => 20 )
```

Where is 15? :) Tnx.

Comment: When a capture group is repeated the last value overwrite the previous.

Comment: Sorry. i don't understand the answer below from vks.
How i can capture all value in my example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a capture group is repeated in a pattern the previous values are overwritten with the last. So it is not possible to design your pattern like this with `preg_match`.

A possible workaround consists to use `preg_match_all` that searches all occurrences of a pattern and the `\G` anchor that is the position after the previous match. The pattern must be written to find one value at a time.

The `\G` ensures that all matches are contiguous. To be sure that the end of the string has been reached (in other word that the string is correctly formatted from start to the end), a convenient way is to create an empty capture group at the end. So if this capture group appears in the last match, that means that the format is correct.

```
define('PARSE_SENTENCE_PATTERN', '~
(?:                                       # two possible beginings:
    \G(?!\A)                              # - immediatly after a previous match 
  |                                       # OR
    \A                                    # - at the start of the string
    (?<subject> \w+ (?>[-.]\w+)*? ) -is-  #  (in this case the subject is captured)
)
(?<value> \w+ (?>[-.]\w+)*? )  # capture the value
(?: -or- | \z (?<check>) )     # must be followed by "-or-" OR the end of the string \z
                               # (then the empty capture group "check" is created)
~x');

function parseSentence ($sentence) {

    if (preg_match_all(PARSE_SENTENCE_PATTERN, $sentence, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) &&
        isset(end($matches)['check']) ) 
        return [ 'subject' => $matches[0]['subject'],
                 'values'  => array_reduce ($matches, function($c, $v) {
                                  $c[] = $v['value']; return $c; }, $c = []) ];

    return false; // wrong format

}

// tests
$test_strings = ['accuracy-is-5', 'accuracy-is-5-or-15', 'accuracy-is-5-or-15-or-20',
                 'package-is-dip-8-or-dip-4-or-dip-16',
                 'bad-format', 'bad-format-is-', 'bad-format-is-5-or-'];

foreach ($test_strings as $test_string) {
    var_dump(parseSentence($test_string));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
^\w+(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+\K|\G(?!^)-(\d+)(?:(?:-[a-zA-Z]+)+|$)
```

You can use `\G` here to capture all groups.Whenever a capture group is repeated the last value overwrites the previous.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/3

> \G assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match

EDIT:

```
^\w+-is(?:-dip)?\K|\G(?!^)-(\d+)(?:-or(?:-dip)?|$)
```

You can use this if you are sure of `is,or and dip`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tS1hW2/4

```
$re = "/^\\w+-is(?:-dip)?\\K|\\G(?!^)-(\\d+)(?:-or(?:-dip)?|$)/m"; 
$str = "accuracy-is-5\naccuracy-is-5-or-15\naccuracy-is-5-or-15-or-20\npackage-is-dip-8-or-dip-4-or-dip-16"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Too difficult example for understanding. Can u show using "\G" on my regexp?

Comment: Example: "package-is-dip-8-or-dip-4-or-dip-16"

"package" - its an attribute name. variable (like size, length etc)

"-is-" - always present in string (one time)

"dip-8" - its option for attribute. variable (package may be dip-8, dip-4 etc. Or black, white ... window, door).

"-or-" - present only if attribute options more than one.

Comment: preg_match('/^\w+-is(?:-dip)?\K|\G(?!^)-(\d+)(?:-or(?:-dip)?|$)/m', 'accuracy-is-5-or-15-or-20', $matches);  
                print_r($matches);    
Result: Array ( [0] => )

Comment: In regexp should not be "dip". It's variable, option name.  
"accuracy-is-5-or-15", "package-is-dip-8" .... "window-color-is-white-or-black"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/cruWk8MT  
No :(  
From string "package-is-dip-8-or-dip-4-or-dip-16" i need to get an array where are substrings: "package" (it's attribute name), "dip-8", "dip-4", "dip-16" (its attribute options)

Comment: It's not correct. In array only numbers (8, 4, 16). I need in that format "dip-8", "dip-4" and "dip-16". And there are not an attribute name (package).

Comment: Now so close) http://pastebin.com/zA0zGeTu
But where is substring "package" in array? And there are empty value for first element.